# Resume play function on standard music app for Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, music

How can I get the standard Music app for my S2 to resume play from where I had got to in a podcast, rather than having to start the whole 90 minutes again?

I operate on Android version 4.0.3